# Exception : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammerException and org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCEXception

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, hql

This is HQL query :

```
SELECT COUNT(s)
FROM Site s  JOIN s.topics t
INNER JOIN t.topicExpertAssignment tea
INNER JOIN tea.expert u 
INNER JOIN u.userinfo info
WHERE tea.assignedBy.id = 1 AND s.createdBy = tea.expert.id
ORDER BY s.name
```

when i try to run this `HQL` query first time , it Generate `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammerException: could not execute query` exception and when i try to run again this query it generates `org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCEXception: could not execute query` exception. without `COUNT()` the query run successfully. how to resolve this exceptions and thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Query is incorrect, because ORDER BY references to `s.name`, and `s.name` is not one of the items in select list.

Most likely correct solution is to remove `ORDER BY s.name`. It does not make too much sense to define order when result is one value.